# Sphinx does not recognize subfolders

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc, toctree

I'm new in using *Sphinx*. I'm able to create HTML documentations as long as my files are in the `source` top folder.

As soon as I'm putting them in a subfolder in the `source directory`, *Sphinx* does not include the document into the build. *Sphinx* tells me after generating that the test document is not included. So, it sees the file but does not include it.

Did I miss anything? Do I have to specify any subfolders in the `index.rst` file or in the `config.py`?

My `index.rst` file:

```
Welcome to python help's documentation!
=======================================

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Contents:

   test

Indices and tables
==================

* :ref:`genindex`
* :ref:`modindex`
* :ref:`search`
```

My `config.py` file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#
# python help documentation build configuration file, created by
# sphinx-quickstart on Mon Jul 31 18:39:52 2017.
#
# This file is execfile()d with the current directory set to its
# containing dir.
#
# Note that not all possible configuration values are present in this
# autogenerated file.
#
# All configuration values have a default; values that are commented out
# serve to show the default.

# If extensions (or modules to document with autodoc) are in another directory,
# add these directories to sys.path here. If the directory is relative to the
# documentation root, use os.path.abspath to make it absolute, like shown here.
#
# import os
# import sys
# sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('.'))


# -- General configuration ------------------------------------------------

# If your documentation needs a minimal Sphinx version, state it here.
#
# needs_sphinx = '1.0'

# Add any Sphinx extension module names here, as strings. They can be
# extensions coming with Sphinx (named 'sphinx.ext.*') or your custom
# ones.
extensions = []

# Add any paths that contain templates here, relative to this directory.
templates_path = ['_templates']

# The suffix(es) of source filenames.
# You can specify multiple suffix as a list of string:
#
# source_suffix = ['.rst', '.md']
source_suffix = '.rst'

# The master toctree document.
master_doc = 'index'

# General information about the project.
project = u'python help'
copyright = u'2017, Stephan'
author = u'Stephan'

# The version info for the project you're documenting, acts as replacement for
# |version| and |release|, also used in various other places throughout the
# built documents.
#
# The short X.Y version.
version = u'0.0.01'
# The full version, including alpha/beta/rc tags.
release = u'0.0.01'

# The language for content autogenerated by Sphinx. Refer to documentation
# for a list of supported languages.
#
# This is also used if you do content translation via gettext catalogs.
# Usually you set "language" from the command line for these cases.
language = None

# List of patterns, relative to source directory, that match files and
# directories to ignore when looking for source files.
# This patterns also effect to html_static_path and html_extra_path
exclude_patterns = []

# The name of the Pygments (syntax highlighting) style to use.
pygments_style = 'sphinx'

# If true, `todo` and `todoList` produce output, else they produce nothing.
todo_include_todos = False


# -- Options for HTML output ----------------------------------------------

# The theme to use for HTML and HTML Help pages.  See the documentation for
# a list of builtin themes.
#
html_theme = 'alabaster'

# Theme options are theme-specific and customize the look and feel of a theme
# further.  For a list of options available for each theme, see the
# documentation.
#
# html_theme_options = {}

# Add any paths that contain custom static files (such as style sheets) here,
# relative to this directory. They are copied after the builtin static files,
# so a file named "default.css" will overwrite the builtin "default.css".
html_static_path = ['_static']


# -- Options for HTMLHelp output ------------------------------------------

# Output file base name for HTML help builder.
htmlhelp_basename = 'pythonhelpdoc'


# -- Options for LaTeX output ---------------------------------------------

latex_elements = {
    # The paper size ('letterpaper' or 'a4paper').
    #
    # 'papersize': 'letterpaper',

    # The font size ('10pt', '11pt' or '12pt').
    #
    # 'pointsize': '10pt',

    # Additional stuff for the LaTeX preamble.
    #
    # 'preamble': '',

    # Latex figure (float) alignment
    #
    # 'figure_align': 'htbp',
}

# Grouping the document tree into LaTeX files. List of tuples
# (source start file, target name, title,
#  author, documentclass [howto, manual, or own class]).
latex_documents = [
    (master_doc, 'pythonhelp.tex', u'python help Documentation',
     u'Stephan', 'manual'),
]


# -- Options for manual page output ---------------------------------------

# One entry per manual page. List of tuples
# (source start file, name, description, authors, manual section).
man_pages = [
    (master_doc, 'pythonhelp', u'python help Documentation',
     [author], 1)
]


# -- Options for Texinfo output -------------------------------------------

# Grouping the document tree into Texinfo files. List of tuples
# (source start file, target name, title, author,
#  dir menu entry, description, category)
texinfo_documents = [
    (master_doc, 'pythonhelp', u'python help Documentation',
     author, 'pythonhelp', 'One line description of project.',
     'Miscellaneous'),
]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to include the relative path to the `.rst` source file in the subdirectory.

```
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Contents:

   test
   dir1/file
   dir2/*
```

In `dir1` only the file named `file.rst` would be included in the TOC. You can exclude files in there, too.

In `dir2` all files would be included in the TOC via globbing syntax.

For further information, see documentation of the [`toctree` directive](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/markup/toctree.html).

Comment: I tried that also but used a \ instead of a / to define the path. Thanks.